# understand of span, linear independence and basis by using dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Before start explaining what makes me confused, I'm sorry about my poor English. I'm not good at English. lol

> If $V$ is Finite-dimensional vector space, let $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is arbitrary basis of $V$.

> (a) The set of vectors that have more than $n$ is linearly dependent set.

> (b) The set of vectors that have less than $n$ can't span $V$

I wanna know that (b) means if we have more than $n$ vectors when the basis of the V is $n$, we can just span V.

I'm confused because I'm not sure about the concept of span and linear combination exactly.

> If $S=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r\}$, $S'=\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_k\}$ is a vector set that is included in vector space $V$, if and only if $span\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r\}=span\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_k\}$ is that each vector of S is linear combination of $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_k$ and also each vector of $S'$ is linear combination of $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r$.

I wanna know this sentence is right.
`If there are **n**-times basis* *(I mean the number of the basis vector is n)* and n≦r, n≦k then S,S' can span vector space V and also S,S' is linearly dependent set.`

Comment: The Question is poorly framed.   The highlighted passage mentions $S,S'$ as having equal spans.  Your "I wanna know this sentence is right" talks about `S,S'` as a set, but those are two sets.  It's unclear if you are asking the same question about both sets or you mean that they are combined together in one set.

Answer (score 2):

A set of $n$ vectors in an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ needs not be a base for $V$. Think of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\{(1,0),(2,0)\}$. We need the vectors to be linearly independent to actually be a base of $V$.

If the vector space has dimension $n$ in any set of $r>n$ vectors there will be **at most** $n$ that are linearly independent, but the actual number of linearly independent vectors will be between $1$ and $n$. If there exist precisely $n$ linearly independent vectors, those will form a basis of $V$ and will span $V$. Any base of the vector space spans it.

Answer (score 1):

On the matter of your first question (i.e., "Must a set of more than $n$ vectors span a vector space of dimension $n$?"), I believe that you are misinterpreting the logic. The statement (b) says that, "If $|S| < n,$ then the vectors of $S$ cannot span $V.$" Put another way, it says that, "If the vectors of $S$ span $V,$ then we must have that $|S| \geq n.$" This equivalence is due to the fact that the implication $P \implies Q$ is *logically equivalent* to the contrapositive $(\neg Q) \implies (\neg P).$ One can see this by typing `(p=>q)<=>(!q=>!p)` into [this truth table generator](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) from Stanford.

Unfortunately, it is not true that every set $S$ of at least $n$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ must span $V.$ One of the silliest examples is to look at the set $S$ that consists of $m \geq n$ copies of the same vector $v.$ In this case, we have that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{span} \{v, v, \dots, v\} &= \{c_1 v + c_2 v + \cdots + c_m v \,|\, c_1, c_2, \dots, c_m \text{ are scalars}\} \\ \\
&= \{(c_1 + c_2 + \cdots + c_m) v \,|\, c_1, c_2, \dots, c_m \text{ are scalars}\} \\ \\
&= \{cv \,|\, c \text{ is a scalar}\} \\ \\
&= \operatorname{span} \{v\}. \end{align*}
By definition, one vector cannot span an $n$-dimensional vector space (whenever $n > 1$).